# Automatically Open Java App After Finish Install Java JRE from java.com

Tags: java

I am currently working on java application project. My application need to run on Java Runtime Environment (JRE). I have wrap my jar file into .exe file,

When the user clicked our .exe file, if the user dont have JRE installed in their device(Windows OS computer), they will be direct to java download [here](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp). This link will download and install the jre to user computer.

to ease user, my superior instruct me to automatically open our java application after the jre have finish installed into user computer. is it possible, if yes what is the common practice of how to do it.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: so i guest, the common practice is just to make the user manually open again the application after they have finish installing jre right. Probably the idea to make our application run automatically after download from third party site is undoable. :)

Comment: Use batch command for that. Continuously check whether jre installed or not with some sleep interval, After the successful installation run your app by batch itself. Refer batch processing it'll useful for you.

Comment: brilliant suggestion, that one might do. Thanks @Surendar Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of research, i conclude it is not possible to do that in this current time but instead the best alternative is to let the installer to check for JRE environment before installing our application. User will have to download and install first JRE and only after that they will be allowed to finish the installation. i use advance installer for installation package.